# how to update script link in html

Tags: javascript, gulp

I wash to update script link in  index.html of dist file directory, but this code can't update script link? how to update it?

thanks !
use this link to download my project --  [clickthis](https://github.com/wei63w/testgulp)

```
var jsSrc = ['js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js','js/customer.js'];
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('clean','minifyjs','revCollector');
});
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['minified/css', 'minified/js','rev/js','dist/'], cb)
});
gulp.task('minifyjs', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))    
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))   
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())    
        .pipe(rev())        
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js')) 
        .pipe(rev.manifest())    
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js')); 
});
gulp.task('revCollector', function() {
    return gulp.src(['dist/js/*.json','index.html']) 
        .pipe(revCollector({
            replaceReved: true
        })) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change html file script link same to rev-manifest.json key .it worker !